# Access application portal from internet

Tags: web, virtual-machine, portal, f5

There is a portal which is currently accessible through intranet. Say, the request comes first to F5 (internal load balancer of the organization) then F5 to portal connection is established. Now, due to need, want to publish the portal in internet. Flow will be same like the request will land to F5 then F5 will forward request to the portal. Can anyone let me know what could be approaches to do this and what will be the best approach in such cases with minimal change.

Comment: Can anyone please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this with Access Policy Manager (APM) for BIG-IP if you have that licensing. This chapter on Web Access Management should achieve what you've described: https://techdocs.f5.com/en-us/bigip-16-1-0/big-ip-access-policy-manager-implementations/web-access-management.html#GUID-53DDB815-D109-4BE3-B30A-BD08FA6A2F4B

Comment: Actually don't have that license. Let me elaborate the scenario a bit; say currently the URL of my portal is http://10.16.176.68:5000/main/login.html where it lands first to central F5 LB then from LB it routes to the webserver. Now what I want to achieve is, converting the portal to https://www.mywebsite.com/ I can issue SSL certificate & also can give entry to DNS for the FQDN resolution. The user flow will be same as now (F5-->LB). Do I need any public IP address to achieve this or by which means I can comply this. Need some step by step guidelines or any reference would suffice.

Comment: but the URL should be accessible by public network(not only within the organization)

Comment: In that case, this doc will cover that: https://techdocs.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm-implementations-12-1-0/17.html